# how to return a url in model and view method?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

In my jsp i am calling a method in my controller like this

```
<a href='<c:url value="/buy/purchase.sp?${Constants.PART_NUMBER}=${suites.partNumber}&${Constants.ID_PARAM}=${suites.entitlementId}&${Constants.LICENSE_TYPE}=${suites.licenseType}&${Constants.QUANTITY}=1&Return_url=${Constants.HOME_URL}&attribName=${Constants.EXISTING_ID}"/>'>
<img src="/licensing/images/purchase.gif" alt="Purchase More Seats" border="0" /></a>
```

on click of purchase option in my jsp it goes to method purchase where i process all these values like this after geting from url

```
String myUrl = appPath+"/"+DevTechConstants.ECOMMERCE_URL+"?PART_NUMBER="+partNumber+"&entitlementId="+entitlementId+"&ITEM_TYPE="+itemType+"&QUANTITY=1&RETURN_URL="+DevTechConstants.HOME_URL+"&attribName="+DevTechConstants.EXISTING_ID+"&licenseType="+licenseType;
```

and after this it should navigate to url in myurl
im passing this value like this `return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("myUrl"));`

But its showing error..
please help me in how to redirect after click on my jsp with values in jsp to other url.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a typo with your code.

Just remove the double quots from

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("myUrl"));
```

and then it will look like below.

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(myUrl));
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: :no its not navigating.. i want that onclick of purchase on my jsp it should navigate to the url in myUrl.. how can i do it in model and view(how to return that value to the url)

Comment: I am not able to understand what exactly you are trying to do here. You are able to come in the controller when you click on the purchase. And after that you want to redirect to another url?? Am I right?? In that case you should the mapping for the value in **DevTechConstants.ECOMMERCE_URL**.

Comment: :yes ur right,DevTechConstants.ECOMMERCE_URL no issues with this i am able to get the url in string myUrl.i want onclick of purchase it should navigate to the url value in myUrl

Comment: You are getting that url stringin myUrl doesn't mean that it will be navigated. Do you have bind that url to any other controller??

If there is no mapping then this will not work.

Comment: :thanks, but am i need to map that url..with out mapping will not move to the page of myUrl.My case is on click of purchase it should come to controller and should navigate to url like WWW.Google.com(im giving some other url value) and try to redirect to that url using like this return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(myUrl));

Comment: Ohh.. That means you want to navigate to the url outside of your system. Need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.sendRedirect("myUrl")
```